# Ignoring bad line starting with '“options'

Tags: wireless

I am trying to install a WiFi driver, but I get this message when I try to execute the command.

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:  
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'  
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse:  
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with '“options'
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should include the contents of the file (in this case `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`) to help us troubleshoot your problem...

Comment: Thank you, but i am not quite sure how i do that

Comment: Use in terminal `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Use the sed command to comment out the line or fix the issue

```
sudo sed -i 's/"options/options/' /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Then reboot

I am guessing you put a double quote in a `sudo tee -a` you can check in terminal with `history | grep echo`

Comment: He may also have trailing quotes.